# Why my textBrowser wraps when display a string

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I use **textBrowser.append** to display this string in textBrowser.

```
CC0wqqqqqqqqqqqqwqwm0QCYYXYUYcjtnvn(lii;!Iff/fczc|1~,i-?uX)txft?_\/1r/fU0mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

It will automatically wrap the line in the middle

[image]

I try to use repr(), but it doesn't work.

The code.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(640, 720)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(45, 85, 550, 550))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")


class Dlg(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dlg, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlg = Dlg()
    dlg.show()
    s = "CC0wqqqqqqqqqqqqwqwm0QCYYXYUYcjtnvn(lii;!Iff/fczc|1~,i-?uX)txft?_\/1r/fU0mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
    dlg.textBrowser.append(s)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use `.setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit.NoWrap)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added `self.textBrowser.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextBrowser.NoWrap)`

if you change geometry (i.e. self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(45, 85, 850, 550)) everything will be on one line, think is the way the class Wraps automatically text

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(640, 720)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(45, 85, 550, 550))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextBrowser.NoWrap)  ######### added this 

class Dlg(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dlg, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dlg = Dlg()
    dlg.show()
    s =  "CC0wqqqqqqqqqqqqwqwm0QCYYXYUYcjtnvn(lii;!Iff/fczc|1~,i-?uX)txft?_\/1r/fU0mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
    
    dlg.textBrowser.setText(s)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```